# Loading list of data which references related data in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**SOLVED**

I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve a collection of related data from a table in entity framework, but I haven't solved it yet.

It is a many-to-many relationship between the two tables as shown in the image below:

[image]
[image]

My problem is that I want to retrieve the related BOOKs to an Author which is a ICollection of the BOOK table but it gives me an empty list instead when I do the return.
I have tried solving this using explicit loading:

```
public AUTHOR Read(int Aid)
{
    using(var db = new LibraryDBEntities1())
    {
        var author = db.AUTHORs.Find(Aid);
        db.Entry(author).Collection(a => a.BOOKs).Load();

        return author;
    }
}
```

I have also tried sloving it using eager loading

```
return db.AUTHORs.Where(a => a.Aid == Aid).Include("BOOKs").FirstOrDefault();
```

but it didn't work either. I tried to follow the documentation on microsoft docs [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) but I have not been able to figure out what it is I am doing wrong.
Can somebody please help me with this problem and maybe explain where I do wrong?

**EDIT 1** 
This is what the OnModelCreating looks like. Should I change/add code here? I have been using a Database First approach.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The database junction should look like this:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I've forgotten to mention that I'am using a 3-layered architecture including a presentation layer(MVC), a business logic layer and a data access layer. And also a data layer which includes the database, as seen in the image below.

[image]

**SOLUTION**

So i finally solved it! So the problem was not really the problem that I first thought rather it had to du with how I use my Mapper. 
I had to add the following code i my model to get it to work:

```
authorObj.BooksList = Mapper.Map<List<BOOK>, List<Book>>(aauthor.BOOKs.ToList());
```

Now it works as it should!

Comment: how did you define many-many relationship in your c# model (could you post the snippet from your context file's OnModelCreating

Comment: @sam Thank you for your comment! I'm new to entity framework so I didn't know that I should have changed anything in the context file. I have edited the question and added a snippet on the OnModelCreating

Comment: what EF version you are using?

Comment: @ilkerkaran I'm using EF version 6.4.0

Comment: @JulijusErgül you dont suppose to do anything. I think something wrong with your `..Include("BOOKs")` could you try `Include(a => a.Books)`?

Comment: @ilkerkaran I tried the code you suggested, but I still get an `null` as a result

Comment: @JulijusErgül OnModelCreating you should have called `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` by the way. And also you should be able to find a junction table in your database like 'AuthorBook'

Comment: @JulijusErgül, what is the junction Database table structure? Could you post that as well? Also, is it code-first or database first?

Comment: @ilkerkaran Thanks! I've added the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` to OnModelCreating

Comment: @sam I update the Question with the junction table structure and it's database first approach i've been using

Comment: @JulijusErgül, you basically need to create a model for the junction table. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @JulijusErgül Thank you. Please check my answer, have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since, its database first approach, please try adding below mapping to your `OnModelCreating` function

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<BOOKs>()
        .HasMany<AUTHORs>(b => b.AUTHORs)
        .WithMany(a => a.BOOKs)
        .Map(m => m.ToTable("BOOK_AUTHOR")
        .MapLeftKey("ISBN")
        .MapRightKey("Aid"));

// or like below
       /* modelBuilder.Entity<BOOKs>()
         .HasMany<AUTHORs>(s => s.AUTHORs)
         .WithMany(c => c.BOOKs)
         .Map(cs =>
         {
              cs.MapLeftKey("ISBN");
              cs.MapRightKey("Aid");
              cs.ToTable("BOOK_AUTHOR"); // Use the correct junction table name here. and correct key names
         });*/
    }
```

Also, remove the statement that throws exception.

And then use:

```
db.AUTHORs.Include("BOOKs").Where(a => a.Aid == Aid).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
db.AUTHORs.Include(a => a.BOOKs).Where(a => a.Aid == Aid).FirstOrDefault();
```

or simply, directly have predicate in FirstOrDefault without WHERE clause.

```
db.AUTHORs.Include(a => a.BOOKs).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Aid == Aid); // Same as above two queries.
```

**UPDATE**:

```
var query = db.AUTHORs.Include(a => a.BOOKs).Where(a => a.Aid == Aid);
var firstBook = query.FirstOrDefault(); // Have a break point here. Please see what is in query via quick watch.
```

In quick watch for query (not firstBook), you should see Sql as shown below:

[image]

Please take that SQL statement and post your observations here after executing directly in SSMS like

- do you see a join to BOOKs in the query or not
- and  does the result set has columns from BOOKs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried doing it this way also, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Also, could you tell whether LazyLoadingEnabled and ProxyCreationEnabled is true or false. or post your context's constructor

Comment: I get the following response from quick watch when  for query `error CS0103: The name 'query' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: hmm... did you name the variable as query as something? could you post the code?

Comment: Here is the code that I wrote `var query = db.AUTHORs.Include(a => a.BOOKs).Where(a => a.Aid == Aid);
                var firstBook = query.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Did you get the error "The name 'query' does not exist in the current context" when you are in that function scope or outside the variable scope? Error tells me that you tried to watch the variable "query" when control is not able to access the variable.

Comment: I added the break point where you suggested and added query to quick watch at that same breakpoint and got the error.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error. You should be able to View the variable in "Quick Watch" Window after the break point is hit in debug session. Another way to get the SQL statements is adding logging at database level via Database.Log = <your_log_file_target> (OR) launching SQL Profiler and execute the code after launching SQL profiler.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me! I was able to solve the problem. It had to do with the way I use the AutoMapper in my project and not, as i first thought, with the EF query.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out finally. Thanks for letting me know the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

EF 6 includes default conventions for many-to-many relationships. You need to include a collection navigation property at both ends. So your model class definitions are absolutely fine. What you should do is updating `OnMOdalCreating` like below;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Then you can use it like below;

```
return db.AUTHORs.Where(a => a.Aid == Aid).Include(a => a.BOOKs).FirstOrDefault();
```

P.S: I strongly recommend you to create a model class for the junction type.

**EDIT**
With Database first approach you have to basically create a model class for each table in the database.

So don't change your `OnMOdalCreating` method. Add a new Class like below;

```
[Table("BOOK_AUTHOR")]
public class BookAuthor
{
    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

then you need to bind the properties to primary key properties via attributes or FLuent API. After that, you will be able to get an author with books like below

```
var authorWithBooks = context.Authors
    .Include(a => a.BookAuthors.Select(ba => ba.Book))
    .Where(...)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried it but it didn't work. Do you think I should Migrate to  Code-First instead of database First and then create a model class for the junction table or can I add it right now with the approach i'm taking?

Comment: Migrating to Code-First depends on the needs of your project. But I would add a model for junction either way. It gives more flexibility in my opinion

Comment: @ilkerkaran as far as I know, if the junction table does not have any other columns than primary keys of both tables. So, in this case as the OP does not have additional columns, having an explicit model (public class BookAuthor... ) is not required.

Comment: In which class should I add `var authorWithBooks = context.Authors
    .Include(a => a.BookAuthors.Select(ba => ba.Book))
    .Where(...)
    .ToList();` ?

Comment: How do I bind the properties to primary key?